# Dired: can't create a regexp to hide all the necessary files

Tags: dired, regular-expressions

I read the following article: http://qerub.se/hiding-hidden-files-in-emacs-dired about hiding certain files in dired mode. I decided to hide more files and added a shortcut Alt-q, that will toggle the visibility of:

1. All the hidden files, starting with dot.
2. All Emacs backup files, ending with '~'.

I wrote the following code:

```
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\.$|~$")
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
                (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-q") 'dired-omit-mode)
      ))
```

But only ~ files are hidded, not those, starting with dot. What is wrong?

Comment: Try testing your regex using `M-x regex-builder` to troubleshoot. I used tool to generate this `"^\\..+~?$"` which should work for you.

Comment: @Melioratus Thx, will do.

Comment: Please post if the regexp works. Thanks!

Comment: @Melioratus It works and is simpler, than made by `abo-abo`. But it's better to use this one: `"^\\..*~?$"`. It will hide the `.` directory too.

Comment: @Melioratus Done, but can't accept now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing with `emacs -q` to ensure no customizations:

```
(require 'dired-x) ;; provides dired-omit-mode
```

`M-x dired` `~` -> Backup files and dot files are both present (had to manually add backups since I store them in a dedicated folder by default.

1. `M-x dired-omit-mode` -> Backup files are hidden
2. `M-x dired-omit-mode` -> All files visible again
3. `(setq dired-omit-files "^\\..*$")` -> Omit dotfiles
4. `M-x dired-omit-mode` -> Backup and dotfiles are hidden.

Docstring for `dired-omit-mode` makes reference to `dired-omit-extensions`.  Looking in there, the 2nd extension listed is `~` (emacs backup files).  This comes from `completion-ignored-extensions` (following dock string).

This means by default `dired-omit-mode` will already remove backups from the view, reducing the complexity of the regexp needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:

```
(setq dired-omit-files "^\\(?:\\..*\\|.*~\\)$")
```

Comment: What do you think about this regexp: `"^\\..*~?$"`, invented by Melioratus and me?

Comment: That regex will only match `<dot><anything><optional~>`.  If you want `starts-with-dot or ends-with-tilde` then you need to look for both independently.  Making both optional inline (`^\\.?.*~?$`) will end up matching everything, so you need to treat them as alternatives.

Comment: @JonathanLeech-Pepin For some reason my regexp also hides the files, that don't start with dot. Despite the fact, that it shouldn't do it. Can you test on your system and confirm?

Comment: Figured out why, separate answer incoming to clarify

Answer (score 1):

This regexp works successfully: `(setq dired-omit-files "^\\..*~?$")`